# Calculate escape velocity without using energy?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, escape-velocity

Is it practically doable to calculate the escape velocity on the earth not by using the principle of energy conservation, but by calculating the velocity of the particle as a function of time using Newton's equation:
$$\ddot x_t=-\frac {Gm_e} {x_t^2}$$

Where $x_t$ is the distance from the centre of the earth.

Is it doable to solve this equation for $x_t$ and $\dot x_t$ and then find $x_0$ by assuming that $\lim\limits_{t\to \infty}v_t=0$?

Comment: There is an error in the equation.

Comment: It would probably be easier to just find the critical point at which the solutions are no longer periodic.

Answer (score 6):

It is possible, and is easier than you might think with the right trickery.

I'm going to choose my unit system so that $G m_e = 1$ to make the algebra easier, if you want to reproduce the standard formula you'll have to follow the equations with the constants in.

To start with, we're going to define a velocity to turn this from a 1D second order equation into a 2D first order equation:

$v = \dot x$.

We then have

$\dot x = v$, $\dot v = - \frac{1}{x^2}$.

We can now think of this as a problem in phase space, where the solutions we're interested in will start at high $v$ and low $x$ and move towards the $v$ axis. The crucial behaviour is that some of these will then cross the axis at return to $x=0$, while others will asymptote to infinite $x$ and constant $v$.

To find out where the divide is, let's look at $\frac{dx}{dv}$ along the solutions:

$\frac{dx}{dv} = \frac{dx}{dt} \frac{dt}{dv} = \frac{\dot x}{\dot v} = -v x^2$.

This equation is solvable, and little bit of algebra gives us

$x = \frac{2}{v^2 + c}$,

where $c$ is a constant of integration given by $c = \frac{2}{x_0} - v_0^2$, with $x_0$ and $v_0$ the starting values.

We can now see that for $c \leq 0$, the solutions will tend to $x = \infty$ and $v^2 = - c$, while for $c > 0$, the solutions will cross the $v$ axis then decay to $x=0$. So, our limiting criterion for escape velocity is given by

$0 \geq c = \frac{2}{x_0} - v_0^2$,

$v_0^2 \geq \frac{2}{x_0}$,

$v_0 \geq \sqrt{\frac{2}{x_0}}$,

which is the result we wanted. I hope that's helpful, and that you'll be able to do that with constants included if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

Sort of. The standard method to solve that equation (any equation that has $\ddot x = f(x),$ really) is to multiply both sides by $\dot x_t$ so that you can integrate both sides separately... But then the right hand side is $\frac12 \dot x^2 - \frac12 x_0^2$ and you are looking at an energy equation again! Similarly James Cochran in his answer comes out to $x=2/(v^2+c)$ which is a thinly veiled energy balance as well; he does not try to recover the full trajectory and then inspect it.

Aaron Stevens gives a more interesting suggestion in comments which might better serve your needs. I don’t see a great way to do a Fourier analysis on $\ddot x = -GM/x^2$ but we can certainly use established methods to get the actual trajectory from **conservation of angular momentum**, and then classify it.

## How to derive trajectories for central forces

So you are going to have a 2D trajectory, often described in polar coordinates $r,\theta$ and we have $x=r\cos\theta,y=r\sin\theta$ and as a result the acceleration takes the form $$
\vec a = \begin{bmatrix}\ddot x\\\ddot y\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}\ddot r \cos\theta - 2\dot r\dot\theta \sin\theta - r \dot \theta^2\cos\theta \\
\ddot r \sin\theta + 2\dot r \dot \theta\cos\theta - r \dot\theta^2\sin\theta
\end{bmatrix}
$$ which clearly shows a radial component $$\vec a\cdot\hat r=\ddot r-r\dot\theta^2 = -\frac{GM}{r^2}$$and thus using angular momentum $mr^2\dot\theta=L=m\ell$ we can rewrite this as
$$\ddot r-\frac{\ell^2}{r^3} = -\frac{GM}{r^2}.\tag{A}$$
We can then derive a time-independent trajectory from a force law; let $r(t)=s(\theta(t))$ and let primes be partial derivatives with respect to $\theta$ , then the full time derivative will look like$$\dot r=s'(\theta(t))~\dot\theta(t)=\frac{s'(\theta(t))~\ell} {[s(\theta(t))]^2},$$
but the last expression can be written in some sense as $-\ell~(1/s)',$ suggesting a change of intermediate functions to $k(\theta)=1/s(\theta)$ when you have conservation of angular momentum.

From there you can simplify our $1/r^2$ force equation (A) above by computing the second full-time derivative analogously, $$
\ddot r=-\ell ~k''(\theta(t))~\dot\theta(t)=-k^2~\ell^2~k''$$
And then (A) becomes the time-independent
$$k^2 ~k''+ k^3 = k^2/\lambda$$
for $\lambda=\ell^2/(GM).$ Dividing by $k^2$ gives a harmonic oscillator equation for the $1/r^2$ force law,
$$k'' + k = 1/\lambda,$$solved by (WLOG choosing our $+x$-axis as the closest approach) an expression $k = \lambda^{-1} + \epsilon \lambda^{-1}\cos\theta, $so that we have $$r(\theta) = \frac{\lambda}{1 + \epsilon \cos\theta},$$proving as Newton did long ago that Kepler’s orbits of “ellipses with the sun at one focus” are precisely the orbits belonging to this $1/r^2$ force law.

## The critical trajectory and escape velocity

So if we were at a point of closest approach we would hold $r_0 = \lambda/(1 + \epsilon)$ constant while varying the velocity and hence both $\ell$ and $\epsilon$. Eventually we would have $\epsilon = 1$ and the trajectory would escape to 1/0 = ∞ at θ = 180°. If you go to higher $\epsilon$ then you get there at a larger range of angles, and some interesting stuff happens in those angles (you get a negative radius describing the hyperbola that is out past your current trajectory; hyperbolas are disconnected around a symmetry axis).

For the threshold case of $\epsilon = 1$ we therefore have the equations $r_0 = \lambda/2$ and $$
r = 2 r_0 / (1 + \cos\theta) = 2 r_0 / (1 + x/r)
$$
Solving for $r(x)$ and then using $r^2 = x^2 + y^2$ we can derive an equation $x = r_0 - y^2/(4 r_0)$ and the conic section in question is a parabola.

But of course there is the point you are waiting for, $$\lambda = 2 r_0 = \frac{\ell^2}{GM} = \frac{r_0^2 v_0^2}{GM},$$ and hence $v_0 = \sqrt{2GM/r_0}.$ Of course this is using the fact that $\ell = (\vec r\times\vec v)\cdot\hat z = r~v~\sin\phi$ where $\phi$ is the angle between $\vec r$ and $\vec v$; in this case that angle is $90^\circ$.

## Extending to other angles

We can then maybe extend that argument to be more general, and to not just consider the special case where ϕ = 90°, though “energy considerations” say that that’s good enough. So if we are at some position $\theta$ along the curve then we have $r=\lambda/(1 + \cos\theta)$ at that position, but the above does not give $|\vec v|$ but merely $v_\theta$ and we need to figure out this angle $\phi$. For this it might be best to write $1+\cos\theta$ as $2\cos^2(\theta/2)$ maybe. Then a little change $\delta\theta$ induces a change in $r$, $$\delta r = \frac{\lambda}{2}\frac{\sin(\theta/2)}{\cos^3(\theta/2)} \delta\theta= r~\delta\theta~\tan(\theta/2),$$ so that we should have that $\sin\phi = \cos(\theta/2).$

Once that is determined the argument is the same: if you used a lower velocity than the parabolic orbit which happens to go through that point $(r, \theta)$ with that specific tangent vector, you would have a lower eccentricity and your orbit would fall back to being elliptical, so the parabolic velocity is the escape velocity; but the parabolic orbit is given by $$r = \frac{(r~v~\sin\phi)^2}{2GM\cos^2(\theta/2)}$$ and once we substitute in $\sin \phi$ our $\theta$-term drops out and we are left with $$v = \sqrt{\frac{2GM}{r}}.$$